# error: value show is not a member of Unit CaseFileDFTemp.show()

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I ran below code in `databricks` scala notebook but I am getting error.

LIBRARY ADDED : azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.4.0_2.11-1.3.4-uber 
CODE :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,LongType,FloatType,DoubleType, TimestampType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

//datastax Spark connector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.datastax.driver.core.{ConsistencyLevel, DataType}
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.WriteConf

//Azure Cosmos DB library for multiple retry
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.cassandra

import sqlContext.implicits._
spark.conf.set("x","x")
spark.conf.set("x","x")
spark.conf.set("x","x")
spark.conf.set("x","x")

val CaseFileDFTemp = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "case_files", "keyspace" -> "shared"))
.load().show()

CaseFileDFTemp.show()
```

**ERROR:**

> error: value show is not a member of Unit CaseFileDFTemp.show()

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try creating the SQL context and try the show function.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
val CaseFileDFTemp = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "case_files", "keyspace" -> "shared"))
.load().show()
```

Then `CaseFileDFTemp` will have type `Unit`, because the `show()` will "consume" your dataframe. So remove `show()`, then it will work